Can I export smooth effect from blender to an engine?
I'm working on a model and i have applied a smooth effect(you can see this on the image).
My question is, can i export this effect on a fbx file to use it on a engine(UE5)?
I'm trying to avoid subdivision surface to improve perfomance on engine so I'm searching another solution.
Thank you for your answers!

